# Excel VBA - Macro loop until lastrow

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code on Sheet3 (I have a similar code on Sheet4), that is working row by row.

```
Sub Checker(argi As Long)
    If (Range("B" & argi).Text = "Insert") Then
        Call Tiers_1_to_3(argi)
        Call CI_Desc(argi)
        Call Tiers_Desc(argi)
        Call Site(argi)
        Call Support_Group_2(argi)
        Call Support_Group_3(argi)
        Call Product_Name(argi)
        Call Model_Name(argi)
        Call Mgmt_Components(argi)
        Call ITSM_Group(argi)
        Call Only_Values(argi)
        Call MandatoryColors(argi)
    End If
    Range("F" & argi + 1).Select
End Sub
```

This is part of something bigger, this sub 'Checker' contains all the sub routines that work over the main code; since this is running row by row, I want to cast it from a button on the "ThisWorkbook" sheet.

I've came up with several workarounds, but I'm unable to do so.

```
Sub Refresh()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each i In Range("F" & LastRow)
            Call Sheet4.Checker
    Next i
End Sub
```

The Worksheet arrangement is the following:

`Sheet_Portal`: Autopopulates an UserForm with shortcuts to Sheet3 and Sheet4.

`Sheet3`: Data entry sheet with Checker variation 1.

`Sheet4`: Data entry sheet with Checker variation 2.

`Thisworkbook`: This is where I store all the shared info, such as the button that will trigger Checker 1 and 2.

Long story short, I would like some of your powers to help me on this matter.

**UPDATE # 1**

Following your comments, I was able to create a button that triggers the code

```
Sub Refresh()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 5 To LastRow
            Call Sheet4.Checker(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Please check the main code @[EXCEL VBA - Long Value increasing within subroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337671/excel-vba-long-value-increasing-within-subroutines)

**UPDATE # 2**

Please check the sheets I have used and how is managed

[image: Workbook arrangement]

ThisWorkbook code below

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Worksheets("Version Control").Activate
    MainPortal.Show vbModeless
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    MainPortal.Show vbModeless
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 5 To LastRow
        If ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value > 1 Then
            If ActiveSheet.Range("BV" & i).Value = "" Then
                Cancel = True
                MsgBox "Please complete all mandatory values"
            Exit Sub
            Else
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
Sub Refresh()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 5 To LastRow
            Call Sheet4.Checker(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

ThisWorkbook  stores an Workbook_Open for open an userForm at begining of the file and its main button, a Workbook_BeforeSave which check is two values are empty then save file is disabled and the Refresh button.
The main file stores a similar Workbook_BeforeSave which checks mandatory fields.

Comment: `For i = 1 To LastRow` `Call Sheet4.Checker(i)` `Next i` ?  Or, if you are **always** going to check all the rows, put a loop like that into `Checker` and then you don't need to pass it a parameter - it can be called directly from the button.

Comment: Do you really have a sheet called "ThisWorkbook" ?  That's a pretty confusing name...

Comment: If you can avoid "ThisWorkbook" it would be useful; I've had lots of issues with that function (I believe I was once told it was simply antiquated).  After checking what @YowE3K has said, and from my own looking at the above code, you describe "for each i" without utilizing "i", so there is no iteration happening.  Possibly try For each i to LastRow in Range("F1"+i), or something similar.

Comment: I'm not sure how your code should work exactly, but I can see two things may make you program not working - in Sub Refresh you call Checker sub which should contain input argument, but it's not in the code. Second things is that you use For Each but you are going through range which contains always one cell only (F Last row). Is it on purpose? If yes, you don't need for each loop.

Comment: I just followed the YowE3K comments, which made a pretty good outcome.

Comment: Cyril & Rufus, you can check the main code @http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337671/excel-vba-long-value-increasing-within-subroutines